# Format a double without losing precision but with a minimum number of digits

Tags: c++, number-formatting

In our C++ codebase, we have a default formatting method to convert `double` floating point numbers into strings, that is used notably for JSON serialization and for debug logs. For that default number formatting, I have the following contradictory requirements:

1. Favor human readability. Prefer `1000` to `1e3` or `0.125` to `1.25e-1`.
2. Keep the precision. Prefer `3.1415926535897931` to `3.14`.
3. Avoid spurious digits for decimal numbers. Prefer `0.1` to `0.10000000000000001`.

Up to now, the best tradeoff I found is to use the equivalent of `printf("%.15g", value)` formatting. It fulfills requirements **1** and **3**, but not completely **2**. There is a loss of precision of about 4 bits.

Other people use a default formatting based on `"%.17g"`, which fulfills requirements **1** and **2**, but not **3**. The number **0.2** is for example formatted as `0.20000000000000001`.

In between, the format `"%.16g"` is close to fulfill requirements **2** and **3**, but not always for both.

As an illustration, I wish **0.3** to be formatted as `0.3`, but **0.1+0.2**, which is slightly bigger due to rounding errors, to be formatted as `0.30000000000000004` to see the difference.

I wrote the following function that format floating point numbers the way I wish, as a proof of concept. However it is unacceptable on the performance point of view, since it can make up to 34 conversions between `double` and strings, for a limited precision gain over the current implementation with `"%.15g"`.

```
std::string doubleToString(double number)
{
    char buffer[32];
    long long intVal = static_cast<long long>(number);
    if(intVal == number)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%lld", intVal);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=17; i++)
        {
            sprintf(buffer, "%.*g", i, number);
            double readBack = atof(buffer);
            if(readBack == number)
                break;
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

I just realized that Python is already formatting numbers the way I want:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.6 (default, Oct  8 2020, 14:06:32) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0.3
0.3
>>> 0.1+0.2
0.30000000000000004
>>>
```

Is there a way to have the same behavior in C++ without sacrificing too much of performance ?

Comment: Some clues 0.10000000000000001 == 0.1 is `true`. So you can drop the long string. 0.20000000000000001 == 0.2 is `true`. Again drop the long string. But `0.30000000000000004 == 0.3` is `false`. So you can't drop the long string.

Comment: Please define (or have the authors of your requirements define) "spurious digits". That should be a rule instead of a single example. "16 decimal places of 0, followed by the least significant 1" is a definition but probably not what they want.

Comment: It is ambiguous what *"Keep the precision."* actually means for floating point decimal numbers. The binary fraction can generate extremely large number of decimal places, but those digits are not necessarily significant. It is not trivial to figure out how many digits are needed to uniquely identify a `double`.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I don't have written requirements, I tried to explain the need in natural terms. If you have better wording, please tell.

Comment: This sounds a lot like what Stephan talks about in his <charconv> presentation (from cppcon 2019). Try to take a look at it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4P_kbF0EbZM It may be just what you are looking for.

Comment: This is **not** a simple problem. For example, 0.3 cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating-point value, so any code that displays that value as “0.3” is suppressing information. Sometimes that’s what you want and sometimes it’s not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Frodyne comment, I was able to figure out a very simple and fast solution.
The C++17 `std::to_chars` function, by default, formats the floating point numbers to fulfill *shortest round trip* requirement. That mean that all distinct floating point numbers remain distinct after serialization, and the number of characters to format is minimized.
So the conversion can be written like this in standard C++17.

```
#include <charconv>
#include <string>

std::string doubleToString(double number)
{
    char buffer[24];
    std::to_chars_result err = std::to_chars(buffer, buffer+sizeof(buffer), value);
    return std::string(buffer, err.ptr);
}
```

The great news from Microsoft lecture is that in addition to solve the *shortest round-trip* problem, the implementation in MSVC is blazing fast! It is based on the incredible [Ryu algorithm](https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu).

The bad news is that as time of writing `std::to_chars` is only available for floating point numbers in the Microsoft tool chain. The implementations in *Clang libc++* and *GCC libstdc++* are for the moment limited to integer numbers.

Comment: Just use `fmt` library. According to the benchmark provided by the author, it already outperforms Ryu on the author's platform (assuming the uniform random distribution of number of decimal digits). MSVC's `std::to_chars` implementation is basically a wrapper over the original Ryu implementation, so it can't be faster than the original one.

Comment: "Just using the format library" _in case all you need is achievable trivially without it_, is like "just buying the restaurant chain" for a pizza (in terms of complexity, compilation costs, code size bloat, debugging unexpected/obscure error cases etc. etc.).